# Merge in Master from a earlier Branch excluding all the changes in between

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am a git noob.

My current master branch is 2.1.18. Business requested me to create a new branch from the production version and apply changes and push to production. So I created a branch from the production version which was at 2. 1.10. Made changes and created a 
pull request  Now a get the error

```
Conflicts prevent automatic merging
```

How do I merge my current branch which I created from 2.1.10 into master which is 2.1.18 and exclude all the changes from 2.1.10(only include my current changes)- until 2.1.18?

Comment: How is the issue going, didnot you try out Vonc's answer below?

Answer (score 2):

> Business requested me to create a new branch from the production version and apply changes and push to production

If you create a branch from 2.1.10 and not 2.1.18, that means what is running in production is 2.1.10.

So your pull request should not be made against `master`, since it is for pushing to production.

That being said, if you need to report your fix against the latest of `master`, I would:

- leave your existing branch as is (it represents what has been pushed to production)
- create another branch where your current fix branch is
- *rebase* that new branch against `master` (and resolve any merge conflict in the context of that rebased branch)
- make a PR from that rebased branch: no conflict there.

That is:

```
git checkout myFixBranchFrom2.1.10
git checkout -b myFixBranch
git rebase master
```